# Calling C++ function from different places cause different behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm using Qt 5.11, and trying to write a function for showing green mark at avatar corner when user is online.
Test project contains *MainWindow* class and *AvatarBox* class. *AvatarBox* has *QLabel* **labelOnline** for displaying user picture.

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

public slots:
    void slotSetOnline();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //slotSetOnline();    //comment 1
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slotSetOnline()
{
    ui->avatar->setOnline( true );
}
```

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>135</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="AvatarBox" name="avatar">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>100</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>100</width>
        <height>100</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>135</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSetOnline"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionSetOnline">
   <property name="text">
    <string>setOnline</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>AvatarBox</class>
   <extends>QFrame</extends>
   <header>avatarbox.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>actionSetOnline</sender>
   <signal>triggered()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>slotSetOnline()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>-1</x>
     <y>-1</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>199</x>
     <y>149</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
 <slots>
  <slot>slotSetOnline()</slot>
 </slots>
</ui>
```

avatarbox.h:

```
#include <QFrame>
#include <QLabel>

namespace Ui {
class AvatarBox;
}

class AvatarBox : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AvatarBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AvatarBox();

    void setOnline( bool online = true );
private:
    Ui::AvatarBox *ui;
    QLabel *labelOnline = NULL;
};
```

avatarbox.cpp:

```
#include "avatarbox.h"
#include "ui_avatarbox.h"

AvatarBox::AvatarBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AvatarBox)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

AvatarBox::~AvatarBox()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AvatarBox::setOnline(bool online)
{
    if( online )
    {
        if( !labelOnline )
        {
            int size = 10;

            labelOnline = new QLabel(this);
            labelOnline->setScaledContents( true );
            labelOnline->setPixmap( QPixmap(":/icons/online.png") );
            labelOnline->setFixedSize( size, size);
            labelOnline->move( width() - size - 2, height() - size - 2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( labelOnline )
        {
            delete labelOnline;
            labelOnline = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

avatarbox.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>AvatarBox</class>
 <widget class="QFrame" name="AvatarBox">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>144</width>
    <height>144</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>300</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Frame</string>
  </property>
  <property name="frameShape">
   <enum>QFrame::WinPanel</enum>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="labelAvatar">
     <property name="maximumSize">
      <size>
       <width>16777215</width>
       <height>16777215</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="pixmap">
      <pixmap resource="res.qrc">:/icons/empty_avatar.png</pixmap>
     </property>
     <property name="scaledContents">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="res.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

So, the problem. If i call *slotSetOnline()* in *MainWindow* constructor (line with "comment 1"), everything works as it supposed to, the green mark appears:

[image]

But, if I call *slotSetOnline()* from any other place, for example, from MainWindow with QAction, I get this:

[image]

The question is why?

UPDATE:
I really appreciate everyone's help and advices. Just wanted to remark, that the question was why is it happening, and the clear answer was in similar question ( link at post's top).

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger and seeing if your code is getting called?

Comment: Could you reproduce a runnable minimal code of the problem?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to initialize `labelOnline`, leading to undefined behaviour when you later use it.

Comment: @JarMan, of course, it is getting called.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I thought i just did that in the main post. It is not full, but there are only left ui-files and main.cpp. I can post full code, I am just not sure how should I reproduce it, as archive or something?

Comment: @molbdnilo, it is initialized in avatarbox.h with NULL

Comment: @FunnyHorse please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to take a look at the generated MOC code in `"ui_avatarbox.h`, you'll see that the original label object gets created then put into the proper location (correct layouts). Once you delete that item, its gone. Even if you "recreate" by `new`ing a new object, that new object isn't being tracked by the layouts and has nowhere to properly be displayed.

Instead of deleting and newing the label, set the online state by setting a different icon or hiding the object. That way you aren't needlessly creating/destroying objects and it will keep its place in the ui's layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I Edit and change some parts of your code and create this Example for you,
now your slot function will work.

I add pushbutton in mainwindow ui for test calling your function and change hole AvatarBox class , instead of create and delete object you should show/Hide it .

```
#include "avatarbox.h"
#include "ui_avatarbox.h"

AvatarBox::AvatarBox(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AvatarBox)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    int size = 20;

    labelOnline = new QLabel(this);
    labelOnline->setScaledContents( true );
    labelOnline->setPixmap( QPixmap(":/icon/online.png") );
    labelOnline->setFixedSize( size, size);
    labelOnline->move( ui->labelAvatar->width()- size -2,ui->labelAvatar->height()+(size*2.3));
    labelOnline->hide();
}

AvatarBox::~AvatarBox()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AvatarBox::setOnline(bool online)
{
    if( online )
    {
        labelOnline->show();

    }
    else
    {
        labelOnline->hide();

    }
}
```

here is the source of the project :

https://gitlab.com/ParisaHR/stackoverflow

[image]

Comment: thanks to you too. Sadly I don't have enough reputation to give your answer an upvote

Comment: @FunnyHorse , your welcome.